# Embedding Live Camera Images in Flex

Tags: apache-flex

I know how to embed standard images(in JPEG, GIF, and PNG) in Flex but can't figure out how to embed "live" image feeds. For example:

http://pub2.camera.trafficland.com/image/live.jpg?system=geoweb&webid=720&size=half&pubtoken=9362c1f835f07d2d0ebd4db9f4098e5e

Can someone shed some light on this? Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Never mind. I figure it out by using URLRequest, Loader and Timer to achieve this.